# Why is Ito's Lemma not a Theorem?

Tags: stochastic-processes, terminology, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-analysis

From the Wikipedia page (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lemma_(mathematics)), a **Lemma** is described as: " *lemma (pl.: lemmas or lemmata) is a generally minor, proven proposition which is used as a stepping stone to a larger result*"

If we look at **Ito's Lemma** from Stochastic Calculus (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/It%C3%B4%27s_lemma):

Let $f(t, X_t)$ be a function such that $f$, $\frac{\partial f}{\partial t}$, $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}$, and $\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x^2}$ are defined and continuous. If $X_t$ satisfies:

$$dX_t = \mu(t, X_t) dt + \sigma(t, X_t) dW_t$$

then the differential $df(t, X_t)$ is given by Ito's Lemma:

$$df(t, X_t) = \left( \frac{\partial f}{\partial t} + \mu(t, X_t) \frac{\partial f}{\partial x} + \frac{1}{2} \sigma^2(t, X_t) \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x^2} \right) dt + \sigma(t, X_t) \frac{\partial f}{\partial x} dW_t$$

**My Question:** It seems like Ito's Lemma is a major and large result - furthermore, I am quite sure that all theorems are eventually used as stepping stones to prove larger results. Given all this - why do we consider the above as a Lemma and not a Theorem? Why is it not Ito's Theorem instead of Ito's Lemma?

Comment: Usually, such naming is historical - perhaps it was originally presented as a lemma in a proof of another result. In any event, there is no formal difference between "lemma" and "theorem."

Comment: quadratic reciprocity uses Gauss' Lemma, which one might also say "should" be called a theorem.

Comment: And Yoneda's Lemma likewise seems like it should qualify for theorem status.

Comment: In any even, calling a statement a Lemma doesn't mean it isn't a theorem. It's just a name. One person's lemma is another person's theorem.

Comment: Zorn's Lemma is another well known example. As @ThomasAndrews says, it's just a historical reason.

Comment: Boy, would I *love* to have a Mosher's Lemma.

Comment: I have a severe disagreement with the premise of this question, which seems to be shared by the comments/answers: there is utterly nothing wrong with an important result being called a "lemma". A good lemma is a kind of basic fact that *everyone* has overlooked but after someone points it out *everyone* uses it because it makes *everything* easier.

Comment: In the case of Sperner's lemma, it helps avoiding the mix-up with Sperner's theorem. Both results are of equal importance, in my opinion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As stated in the comments, it is due to historical reasons. The specific reasons are recounted by Jarrow and Protter in a footnote in [A short history of stochastic integration
and mathematical finance: The early years, 1880–1970](https://www.ma.imperial.ac.uk/%7Eajacquie/IC_AMDP/IC_AMDP_Docs/Literature/Jarrow_Protter_History_Stochastic_Integration.pdf). In it they say:

"The [book](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet/relay-station?mr=247684) by H. P. McKean, Jr., published in 1969, had a great influence in popularizing the Itô integral, as it was the first explanation of Itô’s and others’ related work in book form. But McKean referred to Itô’s formula as Itô’s lemma, a nomenclature that has persisted in some circles to this day. Obviously this key theorem of Itô is much more important than the status the lowly nomenclature “lemma” affords it, and we prefer Itô’s own description: 'formula'".